# Is there a way to center an element while enforcing it stays on screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I've got two text views A and B. A is a set size with a set margin between it and the parent. B is a variable size.
The goal is to position B centered below A if it fits but not have B go off the screen.

Here's the xml I've currently got for the two elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/element_A"
      android:layout_width="48dp"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      android:text="elem_A"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/element_B"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/element_A"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/element_A"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/element_A"
      android:text="sml"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The image below shows three figures: left is what I'm seeing when element B is small enough (great), middle is what I'm seeing when element B is too big (not good), and right is what I want to see when element B is too big.

[image: Here's a visual explanation of what I'm seeing vs what I want]

As it turns out, switching from ConstraintLayout to LinearLayout actually fixes this problem. I'm still curious if this is possible using ConstraintLayout but for now I'll just use LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/element_A"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="end"
      android:gravity="end"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="elem_A"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/element_B"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="much much longer element B"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Clarification: I don't want to move A when B is too big to be centered under it, I want B to basically switch from app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/element_A"
to app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create LinearLayout and set orientation to horizontal And again you need to create child LinearLayout  and wrap both text feilds into it and set it's layout_gravity to right also set orientation to vertical. After that you need to distribute weight of LinearLayout into both of text feilds equally and also set gravity and layout_gravity to center for both text feilds . Tip :- don't use hard-coded values,instead use match_parent / wrap_content for all elements.

Comment: Wouldn't this shift element A to the left when element B is too big to fit under it? I'm trying to effectively give up on centering B when it's too big to fit and keeping A in the same place.

Comment: No , if you distribute weight of LinearLayout correctly in text feilds , it won't shift.

Comment: In text feild of element_B.You must use wrap_content for height and set width to match_parent  it will automaticaly wrapped when text it bigger

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment but I'm getting an even weirder view where element A is cut off on the left side when element B is small enough to fit and element B is not centered under it. I'll update my question with the new xml that I'm trying

Comment: I changed it slightly and got rid of the outer linearlayout and played around with the gravities and it worked! Thanks for the suggestion to switch over to linearlayout!

Comment: Please do add weight = 2 for child LinearLayout

Comment: Ohk, sounds great

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to your code, cop-paste all code to your xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/element_A"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="elem_A"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/element_B"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/element_B"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/element_B"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="sml"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="88dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I think that's what I'm currently doing with 
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/element_A"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/element_A"
The problem is that if element B is too large, it goes off the screen to the right